# how to combine code for two separate java builder pattern?

Tags: java

I have a piece of code as below

```
 private Product createProduct(ProductParmas params){

   Product product = repository.getProduct(id)
   ProductBuilder.Builder builder = new ProductBuilder.Builder(); // this is a 
                                                            product builder

   if(product ==  null){
         builder.location("abc").quantity(5).price(10)
         if(parmas.getAvaiability() != null){
              builder.availability(parmas.getAvaiability())
         }

   }

   // I also want to set Availability on obj product, but there are no setters so I have to create an instance of ProductBuilder, copy values from product and also set availability. Is there a cleaner way to come both if product is null or not null and set availability field?
}
```

I also want to set Availability on obj product, but there are no setters so I have to create an instance of ProductBuilder, copy values from product and also set availability. Is there a cleaner way to do this if product is null or not null and set availability field?

Comment: We have no idea what your Product class is but my guess is that if you have no setter for `availability` then this property is either final (not likely) or you are supposed to update it some other way, maybe via some other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no setters on this field, one good way of doing this would be to add a method in your builder that would take a 'Product' as parameter.

Then you could do something like this:

```
   Product product = repository.getProduct(id)
   ProductBuilder.Builder builder = new ProductBuilder.Builder()

   if(product ==  null){
     builder.location("abc").quantity(5).price(10)
     if(parmas.getAvaiability() != null){
          builder.availability(parmas.getAvaiability())
     }

   } else {
      builder.withProduct(product)
             .availability(params.getAvailability())
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But it is not possible to update the builder. ProductBuilder is a generated class from Product class